# Lenovo Y720 Keyboard backlight & Extreme cooling on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, keyboard, backlight

I installed ArchLinux on my Lenovo Legion Y720 laptop and I can't turn on Keyboard lights and Extreme Cooling as I could in Windows 10 using Lenovo NerveSense app. How can I access these on Linux? Is it even possible? I've searched everywhere and I couldn't find anything. Should I try coding a driver? Any literature on that?

Thank you!

Output of `ls /sys/class/leds/*/brightness`:

```
/sys/class/leds/input0::capslock/brightness
/sys/class/leds/input0::numlock/brightness
/sys/class/leds/input0::scrolllock/brightness
/sys/class/leds/input17::capslock/brightness
/sys/class/leds/input17::compose/brightness
/sys/class/leds/input17::kana/brightness
/sys/class/leds/input17::numlock/brightness
/sys/class/leds/input17::scrolllock/brightness
/sys/class/leds/input2::capslock/brightness
/sys/class/leds/input2::compose/brightness
/sys/class/leds/input2::kana/brightness
/sys/class/leds/input2::numlock/brightness
/sys/class/leds/input2::scrolllock/brightness
/sys/class/leds/input5::capslock/brightness
/sys/class/leds/input5::numlock/brightness
/sys/class/leds/input5::scrolllock/brightness
/sys/class/leds/phy0-led/brightness`
```

Comment: The user manual says the keyboard lights can be manipulated with Fn+Space.

Comment: In Windows 10 it can be manipulated with Fn+Space, because there is NerveSense installed and there is set this shortcut, but in Linux it doesn't work.

Comment: Would you mind checking this?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/383501/enable-the-keyboard-backlights-on-supported-lenovo-e-g-carbon-x1-with-command

Comment: I've been here, it's for ThinkPad laptops and it didn't help me, still thanks.

Comment: I edited post. About the CPU governor, I should read [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling)?

Comment: Changing CPU governor doesn't increase fan speed

Comment: Correct.  The Arch wiki also has a page title "Fan Speed Control"

Comment: I'd be tempted to start echoing small values (e.g. 2) to each of those `brightness` files (as root or with `sudo tee`) to see if any changes the status of the backlight.  If not, that is also worth mentioning

Comment: I tried, it didn't help.

Comment: Last time I messed around with this I think I figured out that the backlight came through as a USB device. It will take someone significant effort to reverse engineer it. Its not a normal keyboard backlight. I hope someone does though.

Comment: Here's a Linux solution for the extreme cooling function, which unfortunately doesn't work as it is on my Lenovo Y910, but it may work on yours: [https://odintdh.itch.io/extremecooling4linux](https://odintdh.itch.io/extremecooling4linux) And here are two solutions for the keyboard backlight function, which worked with my Y910 after some hacking and tweaking of the source code: [https://github.com/threadexio/Legion-Y720-Keyboard-Backlight](https://github.com/threadexio/Legion-Y720-Keyboard-Backlight) and [https://github.com/Izurii/Lenovo-Y720-KB-Led-Controller](https://github.com/Izurii/Lenovo-

Answer (score 0):

Since the NerveSense app is made for Windows 10 and mainly gotten no support for Linux, that way it's far from a reality trying the app working.